# javascript 'this' passed as value parameter

Tags: javascript

I had this row:

```
echo "<td style='width:11%' id='client_quote_tr' name='client_quote_tr' onclick='changeColorTaskClientQuote(this);'>".$r['task']."</td>";
```

What's the value of '`this`'? I mean it gets the value of attribute name, or what else?

Comment: `this` refers to the object. In this case (as stated by dystroy), you will get the object of the td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug it. Add a console.log line. Open up the console. Click on the td and see what appears.

```
function changeColorTaskClientQuote(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

You will see it passes a reference to the element you clicked on. Very handy.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/V2VHz/)

Answer (score 1):

`this`, which is the context of the function's execution, is the element on which the event handler was attached. So in this precise case, this will be the `td` element.

If you want to use the name in the function, it's `this.name`.

Answer (score 1):

'this' in an inline event handler will refer to the DOM element the event fired on, in this case your 'td' element.
For more info have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html

Answer (score 0):

`This` is the `td` HTML element of your `table`

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to the DOM element the event is executed on. In this case the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case -- reference to the TD DOM element.